# UpdatePanel not firing inside Wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, wizard

I have an Update panel within a wizard:

```
    <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" StepType="Auto" 
       Title="Set the number of users required.">

       ...
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ProgressInd" Text="Progress..." />
             <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="GoButton_Click" ID="ProgressBtn" Text="Go" />
          </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:WizardStep>

   ...

   protected void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      ProgressInd.Text = "Progress... Moving";
   }
```

When I take the update panel out of the wizard it works nicely but inside the wizard the click event just won't fire.  I'm using Firefox to test, but IE doesn't work either.  Any ideas or help appreciated.

Comment: If you click the button a second time do you find that the text updates?

Comment: Do you have by any chance any validator controls on that wizard step?

Comment: Yes that's it!  I have two validators.  As soon as they pass the event gets posted.  Could you post that as the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record. Paolo spotted my problem.  There were page validators that were preventing the event from firing.